# How do I use the Spring @Autowire to set up TaskScheduler to run method, at a variable n seconds?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, scheduled-tasks

I would like to set spring up to kick off a method every n seconds. But in doing so, n can be adjusted while running

**Method to kick off: PingInvoker.ping()**

```
public class PingInvoker
{
  public void ping()
  {
    List<Server> svr = Manager.getList();

    for (Server i : svr)
      i.ping();
  }
}
```

**Application Context:**

???

Comment: Why don't you want to use Timer class from javaSE for this purposes?

Comment: I need Spring to handle this for Server purposes

Comment: If you deploy a singleton bean which is not lazy and has Timer stuff in constructor it will do what you want

Comment: Can you supply a generic example or show a snippet, relevant to this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PingInvoker {

    public PingInvoker() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new Mytask(), 0, period);
    }

    public void ping() {
        List<Server> svr = Manager.getList();

        for (Server i : svr)
        i.ping();
    }

    static class MyTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          ping();
        }
    }
```

}

You have to deploy `PingInvoker` as singleton bean and specify such `period` as you want